# Windows 8, optical drive not recognized anymore

Tags: windows-8, dvd, compact-disc

As the title says I have a problem with my optical drive in Win 8... I installed windows 8 on my machine less than a month ago, and the drive worked fine until a week ago, when it stopped being recognized by the sistem and didn't show up anymore in device manager, My Computer, cd burner programs and the like.

It's not a hardware problem since I dual boot Linux on this same machine and it works there, also it shows in BIOS.
I have tried the registry fix and the admin command prompt fix which can be readily found, to no effect.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following FixIt from Microsoft:

**[Fix problems with CD or DVD drives that can’t read or write media](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/cd_dvd_drive_problems/en-us)**

**What it fixes...**

```
Your CD or DVD Drive does not read or write and is shown as disabled
The media in your CD or DVD drive cannot be read
The media cannot be written to by your CD or DVD drive
You receive one of the following errors:
    A class specific or device specific driver is missing or corrupt
    A CD or DVD drive cannot be found or is not connected
    The CD or DVD drive is experiencing a problem that prevents it from working properly
    The CD or DVD drive is not accessible via an assigned drive letter
```

Comment: Already tried this, it did no good, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Computer >> Manage >> Device Manager >> Universal Serial Bus Controllers
Uninstall USB Drivers from this location

After that click on Actions >> Scan for hardware changes

It will reinstall all your USB drivers automatically
Then try connecting the ODD
Hope this helps

Comment: It is not an external USB driver, it is an internal IDE one.